# Integrating Factor - Not getting the answer given?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y' - 4y = t$

My integrating factor is $e^{-4t}$

$\int e^{-4t}y'$ - $\int 4e^{-4t}y$ = $\int te^{-4t}$

$\int (e^{-4t}y)'$ = $\int te^{-4t}$

$e^{-4t}y$ = $-4te^{-4t}$ - $e^{-4t}$

I end up with $y' = -4t -1 + ce^{4t}$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: We can't tell you where you went wrong unless you show us your workings.

Comment: Added some steps

Comment: check integration by parts again

Comment: A different way to tackle this ODE, is to recall that any solution $\varphi$ equals $\varphi_h+\varphi_p$ where $\varphi_h$ is a solution of $y'-4y=\bf 0$ and $\varphi _p$ is *one* solution of $y'(t)-4y(t)=t$. It easy to guess a solution $\varphi _p$ just by looking, because the RHS is a polynomial. One can see that $\varphi_p$ given by $\varphi_p(t)=-\dfrac {1}4\left(t+\dfrac 1 4\right)$ is a solution and $\varphi _h$ is very easy to find.

Comment: @GitGud Is there somewhere explaining this method more thoroughly that can be applied to more complex ODE's?

Comment: @Finance The fact that any solution is of the form $y_h+y_p$ can be proven in general. I can show it to you if you want. But the rest doesn't always work out well, it works here because it is simple enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u=t$, $du=dt$, $dv=e^{-4t}$, and $v=-\cfrac{1}{4}e^{-4t}$, then using integration by parts, $\displaystyle\int te^{-4t}\, dt$ should be
\begin{align}
\int te^{-4t}\, dt&=-\cfrac{t}{4}e^{-4t}+\cfrac{1}{4}\int e^{-4t}\,dt\\
&=-\cfrac{t}{4}e^{-4t}+\cfrac{1}{4}\left(-\cfrac{1}{4}e^{-4t}\right)+C\\
&=-\cfrac{t}{4}e^{-4t}-\cfrac{1}{16}e^{-4t}+C\\
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was making a silly mistake with the integral.

Comment: My pleasure. We all do a silly mistake. ヅ

Answer (score 3):

You integrated $\int te^{-4t}\mathrm dt$ incorrectly.  It should be
$$\int te^{-4t}\mathrm dt=-\dfrac{t}{4}e^{-4t}-\dfrac{1}{16}e^{-4t}+c$$
Then multiplying both sides by $e^{4t}$ gives you 
$$y=-\dfrac{t}{4}-\dfrac{1}{16}+ce^{4t}$$

Comment: Ah I see where I went wrong, thanks.